Converse of uniqueness property of Moment Generating Functions
I know the uniqueness property of Moment Generating function, which states that if X and Y have same moment generating function, then they have same distribution. However, does the converse holds, i.e if X and Y have same distribution, does it guarantee that they have same moment generating functions?

You have to be careful with that uniqueness property. The direction you're asking about is simple, but the one you state at the beginning of your question is more delicate. If $X$ and $Y$ have the same m.g.f., and that m.g.f. is finite in an interval with $0$ in its interior, then $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution. But more generally, the property can fail. An interesting example is the log-normal distribution: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/389846 . Its m.g.f. is finite only on $(-\infty, 0]$, and there are other distributions with the same m.g.f.

Yes, if $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution, then $P(X \in A)=P(Y \in A)$ for every event $A$.
In particular, their mass or density functions are equal, so $E[X^{n}]=E[Y^{n}]$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
